# lua-resty-openidc API documentation - Determining if retry is possible

Tags: lua, openid-connect, openresty

Am wondering if there is any documentation for [lua-resty-openidc](https://github.com/zmartzone/lua-resty-openidc). I couldn't find anything during my search, but I would hope that there is something out there that I've missed.

Speficily am looking at this file `openidc.lua`  with this `openidc.authenticate` function; seeing if it’s possible to make use of any a retry mechanism. Am suspecting not but having API documentation would be very helpful to confirm this.

The implementation am using comes from luarocks version: `rocks-5.3`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps but, i've founded the [openidc.lua](https://github.com/zmartzone/lua-resty-openidc/blob/master/lib/resty/openidc.lua) file and the function is in the line 1446.

Comment: Yes this is the exact file that am referring to. The method signature is  `openidc.authenticate(opts, target_url, unauth_action, session_opts)` but is there an API documentation which tells me what are the possible value for `opts`?

Comment: Try changing the script and put `print(opts)` inside the function, so you can find the value.